# Android app to show all the available widgets in a vertical layout and should be able to place them on home screen

Tags: android, widget

I'm looking for an Android app which can show all the widgets available to Android in a vertical layout. I'm currently using Slim Launcher which allows you to place widgets but shows a horizontal layout when browsing them.

It's really painful and time consuming activity to swipe each page from right to left (~15) just to reach a widget available at second last page. Vertical layout makes the things efficient.

See the screenshots for better understanding.

1. I currently have this horizontal layout:

   <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

   [image: IMG:]
2. What I want is something like:

   [image: IMG:] or [image: IMG:]

   These two images depicts functionality available in Apex Launcher and Nova Launcher respectively.

**OS support**: Android 5.0 and above

**Pricing**: Freeware preferred but paid app is fine too

**Device Status**: Rooted and Xposed Framework installed

**Please note** that if you intend to suggest a launcher replacement then make sure that the interface of its app drawer matches almost exactly to the one of Slim Launcher. This is how it looks:

[image: IMG:]

The icons shown in the app drawer of Nova Launcher and Apex Launcher are too small for my taste and the background isn't that smooth.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a highly customizable launcher to fit your needs, try [Total Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.launcher2&hl=en). The choose a widget page is grouped vertically and paged horizontally. The app drawer does have its pros and cons. You can resize it to how ever you see fit, but it only scrolls vertically.

Comment: Hi! Can it show the background like in this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wko1Nl.png? Please confirm with a satisfactory screenshot. I've mentioned that preference in my question.

Comment: It can, showing what it can and can't do is hard since Total Launcher is aimed towards the power users and those who like customize things. Downloading it (only 2MB) and trying out for yourself would be quicker --- http://imgur.com/Cp9CB1T --- (top right) my desktop, (top left) instead of a solid white, made an image as the app drawer background and set red text (bottom left) add widget menu (bottom right) selected an app's widget

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at updated [Google Now launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher)

It shows widgets in vertical layout but then, Apps are shown in vertical layout too.

[image: Widgets Screenshot]
 <sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

Works good with stock android (5.0)

Comment: This seems to be an incompetent launcher. Google didn't update is since an year. No wonder it's not showing up anywhere in my Settings -> Home. It evens asks me to clear defaults of my default launcher and then it does nothing. (Not your fault) but  this seems to be a mess to me. May be it works on other builds but it's not doing anything here.

Comment: @Firelord Even I tried it with another phone with cm12. I have the same problem,  it asks me to clear defaults in trebuchet but I haven't set any.

Comment: Yeah, same here on COS12. The real issue is, when you clear the defaults and try to launch it, you're given the choice to choose one of the available launcher. It happens every time, and the funny thing, Google Now is nowhere to be seen, so you can't select what you can't see.